# Loading assets from internal package in rootBundle

Tags: flutter

I have the below folder structure in my app.

```
./assets
./lib
./pubspec.yaml
./packages/features/the_feature/assets
                               /lib
                               /pubspec.yaml
```

In `the_feature` package I added `data.json` file and declared in `pubspec.yaml`

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/data.json
```

In `the_feature` package I am trying to access the asset with the below code

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> loadDataJson() async {
    final jsonString = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/data.json');
    final jsonList = json.decode(jsonString) as Map<String, dynamic>;

    return jsonList;
  }
```

I get the error `Unable to load asset: '...' The asset does not exist or has empty data.`

If I move the asset in `./assets` main folder it loads as expected. How can I have assets in my custom folder packages?

Answer (score 0):

If you run the app from the root of your directory structure, not from the `the_feature`, you'll get the described error. This is due to how [`rootBundle` works](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/rootBundle.html):

> The AssetBundle from which this application was loaded.

You can access assets of the packages that you depend on (like `the_feature`) using a more specific path for the asset, i.e.:

```dart
final jsonString = await rootBundle.loadString('packages/the_feature/assets/data.json');
```

The above is the same package-relative path defined in the package's `assets`, but prefixed with `packages/<package name>/`.

If you want to understand better how assets are put into the assets bundle, you can check [`AssetManifest.loadFromAssetBundle`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/AssetManifest/loadFromAssetBundle.html) and [`AssetManifest.listAssets`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/AssetManifest/listAssets.html). :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. However, I do remember trying this out in my package with the package feature path. That "If you run the app from the root of your directory structure..." is interesting, not sure I get it...

Comment: If you run your app, and your app is in `./` of the directory structure you described, then you'll need to refer to assets of other packages with the prefix.

If you'd use `Image.asset` for example, it also accepts a `package` parameter, that is then used for building the full asset path.